# How can a java program communicate with already running c++ process

Tags: java, ipc

I have a c++ program named busyreader.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Launching C++ Busy Reader"<<endl;
    for (string line; getline(std::cin, line);) {
        cout << "Busy Reader Process just received " << line << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i am running this code on my mac

make busyreader

./busyreader

I want to write a java program which can pass a string to this already running c++ process. 
I exploited using ProcessBuilder in Java, but it is launching new c++ process every time. but what i am interested in is "How can java code send a string to already running c++ process"?

Comment: Through an RPC mechanism.

Comment: Elliott Frisch,
Thanks for Quick response.
1. is there any work around with ProcessBuilders?


2. do you mean "CORBA" RPC? can you describe in little more detailed way?

Comment: No. ProcessBuilder is used for launching new processes, you want to use IPC (inter-process communication); however, there isn't a "simple" way to do IPC from Java to a pre-running C++ process (at least, I can't think of one). That leaves RPC (remote procedure calls), CORBA (IIOP) is one approach. Sockets, ReST, Thrift, SOAP, protocol buffers, etc...

Comment: If it's just a case of sending a simple string of text, you might be able to use ordinary TCP sockets for this. There's plenty of code around that illustrates creating TCP server and client in both C/C++ and Java. An even easier way that might work on Macs (certainly works on Linux) is to have your C++ program read from a named pipe in much the same way is it currently reads from stdin, and have the Java program write to the named pipe in the same way it would write to an ordinary file. Named pipes usually only work when the processes are on the same host; TCP sockets will work over a network.

Comment: [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) and [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) are another option.

Comment: Problem solved with ProcessBuilders

Here java code only initiates the C++ Process lifecycle, and then communicates through standard console
https://ideone.com/22X18H

Thank you everyone for Quick help.